# WordPress Category or Taxonomy marked, check automatically by default

Tags: wordpress, checkbox, categories, taxonomy

Guys, there's some hook, hack or something that I add on functions that make a taxonomy or category is selected at the time of posting? Already come with chckbox marked to be..

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

you can have a look on this https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_category_checklist
this allow to make categories checked by default. I think this is what you are looking for.

Comment: @Rakid thanks for reply. I think this option is for frontend, I need for backend..

Comment: Let me be clear, whenever user will post something that will automatically pick up one specific category, they user will not have a option to get rid of this, because it will be hard coded in php but not shown to user. Is it what you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks for the reply again @Rakib. The user can view, just wanted the category for example itapema, londres and bangladesh come already marked, without the user having to click the checkbox. Look this exemple http://i.stack.imgur.com/hPx0D.jpg

Comment: Simply you can use this plugin to do so https://wordpress.org/plugins/default-category

Comment: Would be perfect if you work with taxonomies, cuse i need for  taxonomies, I'm not lucky @Rakib :(

Comment: I found this script, but does not work, I'm not as co so to understand why it doesn't work

https://web.archive.org/web/20150214181801/http://wordpress.mfields.org/2010/set-default-terms-for-your-custom-taxonomies-in-wordpress-3-0